# How to calculate weighted percentage for a reactive column?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to calculate the weighted percentage for certain columns that are reactive. I am able to do it on R, with the following code:

```
a <- cbind(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1), c(100, 200, 300, 50, 500))
colnames(a) <- c("gender", "race", "weights")
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

```
a_stack <- a %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(gender, race, weights) %>%
  group_by(gender, race) %>%
  summarize(totalw = sum(weights)) %>% 
  mutate(Percentage = (totalw / sum(totalw)) * 100) %>%
  arrange(gender)
```

This is my output: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz1CD.png).

As can be seen from above, the weights are added up based on the gender/race and I get the end result that I want.

Nonetheless, when I try to convert this to R Shiny and use it in a reactive context, I get this error message ***"Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument."***

This is my code that I used in R Shiny.

```
  completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {
    completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
    return(data[completeVec, ])
  }
```

```
  edited_stackbar <- reactive ({
    completeFun(edited, c(input$x, input$y, input$weight)) %>%
      select_(input$x, input$y, input$weight) %>%
      group_by_(input$x, input$y) %>%
      summarize(totalw = sum(input$weight)) %>%
      mutate(Percentage = (totalw / sum(totalw)) * 100) %>%
      arrange_(input$x) %>%
      mutate(label_pos = cumsum(Percentage) - Percentage / 2,
             perc_text = paste0(round(Percentage), "%"))
  })
```

It is hard to make it reproducible but I believe that the main issue is with the 'summarise' part of things. I am not sure if I should be using a reactive/reactive values function since the weights and variables will change based on the user's input or if I should be using another dataset.

I will greatly appreciate any and all help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If summarize is the error, could you try?

```
 edited_stackbar <- reactive ({
    completeFun(edited, c(input$x, input$y, input$weight)) %>%
      select_(input$x, input$y, input$weight) %>%
      group_by_(input$x, input$y) %>%
      summarize(totalw = sum(edited$nput$weight)) %>%
      mutate(Percentage = (totalw / sum(totalw)) * 100) %>%
      arrange_(input$x) %>%
      mutate(label_pos = cumsum(Percentage) - Percentage / 2,
             perc_text = paste0(round(Percentage), "%"))
  })
```

Or

```
 edited_stackbar <- reactive ({
    completeFun(edited, c(input$x, input$y, input$weight)) %>%
      select_(input$x, input$y, input$weight) %>%
      group_by_(input$x, input$y) %>%
      summarize(totalw = sum(get(input$weight))) %>%
      mutate(Percentage = (totalw / sum(totalw)) * 100) %>%
      arrange_(input$x) %>%
      mutate(label_pos = cumsum(Percentage) - Percentage / 2,
             perc_text = paste0(round(Percentage), "%"))
  })
```

In anycase we have not enought info to answer you. May you show a dput(edited)?

Comment: Hi LocoGris, thank you so much for your help! Your second response worked for me and it's crazy how something so small can affect the results. Nonetheless, thanks once again!